# Mounting an external MyBook drive getting TimeMachine error

Tags: external-hdd

I have a old MyBook that I need to get some files off of.  I am using VirtualBox and Unbuntu as the Guest on a Windows 11 machine.

A few years ago I did the same set up with an older version of Unbuntu to have the drive show as a shared folder. In which I used some sudu code to get it as a shared file.... I think. But I can not do this right now for some reason.

So I added in VirtualBox, a filter.  The filter allowed Unbuntu to see the drive, however, it was used for a TimeMachine back up on an old Mac, which I have none anymore.

That said, when I go to view the mounted drive, I get an error that I did not get on the older version that states "Could not display all contents of My Book: Error getting information from file /media/MyUserName/My Book/com.apple.TimeMachine.supported: input/output error"

Not sure if it is because of the way it is mounted through VirtualBox or if trying to do a different mounting way would work.

Any ideas is super helpful.  Using the latest Unbuntu 22 LTS.